# Displaying image from sanity in Vue (nuxt project)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, sanity

i am new to sanity, i am struggling for displaying image from sanity

this is the code for my frontend
[image]

is this the problem?

```
<img :src="pet.image.asset" :alt="`image of ${pet.name} `" />
```

and this is the result
[image]

and lastly this is the sanity backend
[image]

thank you!

i am expecting the image to be rendered!

Comment: Please, do not post code as image, use code snippets insteads. You can refer to [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Are you sure `pet.image.asset` is a valid url? Or is the problem that the sanity query doesn't return the image?

Comment: Please don't mark a question as resolved by editing the question's title, rather use the specific tools. If you found an answer to be useful then update that answer and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sanity Image component](https://sanity.nuxtjs.org/helpers/images). It will automatically build `img` tag with `href` (Sanity CDN).

```
<li v-for="pet in data" :key="pet._id">
  <sanity-image :asset-id="pet.image.asset._ref" />
</li>
```